# Pass parameters by adress to Macros in Assembly 8086 MASM

Tags: assembly, macros, parameters, x86-16

I have a macro to read user input using Interrupt Int 21,A.
I want to pass the adress of variable 'parcela1' by argument so i can modify it inside the macro.
Printing parcela1 (at the end of the program) prints 2 lines of random chars and 00000000, where it should be the chars entered.
I'm not sure what is wrong, can you help me please?

```
.8086
.model small
.stack 2048

dseg segment para public 'data'
    parcela1    db '00000000$'      ;Var to pass by address.
    InputBuffer db 9,0,8 dup(0),13
dseg ends

cseg segment para public 'code'
assume cs:cseg, ds:dseg

ReadInput MACRO UserInput, maxchar, minchar, x,y

    LOCAL READ_DATA,COPY_DATA

    pushf
    push ax 
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push si

    mov ah,02h              ;position cursor at x,y.
    mov bh,0
    mov dl,x
    mov dh,y
    int 10h

    mov al,maxchar          ;Max number of chars to read.
    add al,1                ;maxchar + 1 (1 for CR).
    mov inputBuffer[0],al
    mov bl,minchar

    mov ah,0Ah              ;INT 21,A - Buffered Keyboard Input.

READ_DATA:
    lea dx,InputBuffer
    int 21h
    cmp InputBuffer[1],bl   ;If chars read < minchar repeat.
    jb  READ_DATA

    xor bx,bx
    mov bl,InputBuffer[1]   ;store num chars read in BL.

    mov cx,bx               ;Loop CX.

    mov si,bx               ;SI - index of last char read in InputBuffer. 
    inc si

    xor bx,bx               ;DI - index of last position of UserInput.
    mov bl,maxchar
    dec bl

COPY_DATA:                  ;copy chars read to parcela1.
    mov al,InputBuffer[si]
    mov [UserInput+bx],al
    dec si
    dec bx
    loop COPY_DATA

    pop si
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx 
    pop ax
    popf
ENDM

Main proc
    mov ax, dseg
    mov ds, ax

    lea si,parcela1         ;Pointer to start of vector.
    ReadInput si,8,1,0,0    ;macro ReadInput 

    lea dx,parcela1         ;print parcela1
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov ah,08h              ;pause.
    int 21h

ENDPROG:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
Main endp
cseg ends
end Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you forgot

```
mov ax, dseg
mov ds, ax
```

at the beginning of your main procedure. `ASSUME` is not enough.

The second error applies the macro.

`ReadInput si,8,1,0,0    ;macro ReadInput`

is a text substitution rule for a substitution at **assembling** time. You cannot pass a computed value to a macro. Hence, when the assembler reaches

`mov [UserInput+bx],al`

it substitutes it to

`mov [si+bx],al`

Since `SI` has changed inside the macro you'll get the wrong pointer and `AL` will be stored elsewhere. If you need to pass arguments which will be computed at **runtime** you have to create a procedure.

The third error is a deep misunderstanding of structure and use of InputBuffer. Please read a reference to `INT 21h/0Ah`, e.g. http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm. Consider also the different end-of-string characters of the buffer in `INT 21h/0Ah` and of the buffer in `INT 21h/09h`.

Comment: I forgot to write those two instructions in my post. Corrected.

Comment: @MiguelPalma: I updated my post, but there's left a lot of work for you getting it to run properly.